# Maintaing a constant # of concurrent threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to get concurrency working in some C++ code, specifically I have a set of about 10k subproblems that I solve individually to look for the best overall solution. I tried creating 8 threads at a time to work concurrently and waiting for them all to join, but the problem with that is that it has to wait for all of the threads to join before launching another 8, i.e. each group of 8 subproblems is only solved as quickly as its slowest solution. How do you set it up so that there are always 8 concurrent threads, that is that a new thread is launched as soon as another ends?

Below is the section of serial code I wanted to convert to parallel:

```
    // Implement multithreading here

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        solver.moves = sols[i];
        Solution cur_sol = solver.solve(s->clone());
        std::cout << "Solution " << i << " had a best possible solve of cost " << cur_sol.cost << std::endl;
        if (cur_sol.cost < best_cost)
        {
            best = cur_sol;
            best_cost = best.cost;
        }
    }

    return best;
```

Comment: Keyword: Thread pool

Answer (score 1):

You need two queues: one for the unsolved and one for the solved solutions. While the unsolved queue is not empty, each thread will pick (pop) a solution from the queue, solve it, and put (push) it into the solved queue.

The main thread could wait until a group is complete and process it.

The only thing that is important here (besides of synchronization) is, that the 'group' solver knows which solved solution belongs to which group.

So, either a big queue or separate queues for each group.